# Cryptomatte Pick isn't working. What have I forgotten?

Tags: compositing-nodes, cryptomatte

Blender 2.81, 2.81a
Windows 10, 2xGTX1080 GPUs, GPU rendering

I've been through the Manual and a few tutorials, but I guess I'm missing something. Why can't I get the Cryptomatte Pick working? Is there another undocumented type of Pass that needs to be activated?

The scene is just the cube. I render the scene, hook up the nodes as below. I've tried both Object and Material options. Tips?

[image]

Comment: Yes. As stated, I tried both types of Cryptomatte - the screenshot just shows the material try. It's still hooked up correctly, and the Pick pass should show me a coloured silhouette of the cube, whichever type of crypto I used.

Answer (score 1):

for me its working pretty good. using this since blender beta.
few tips to find out..

1- try this [sample file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/n1mbdSMN/)
in my case, it looks like this. [image]

steps i did to check

- create objects
- assign materials
- switch to cycles
- turn on cryptomatte (as you have already done )
- hit render
- use cryptomatte nodes in compositor, tested via object and material both.

Comment: Yup, your scene file works on my machine. I did everything in your steps (which was everything in the Manual). Now I have to figure out what massive combination of settings you have that are different from mine :/

Comment: try resetting blender preferences. i am 100% sure, i hadn't tweaked any other settings.

Comment: Nope. Reset doesn't work.

Comment: Back atcha. Does this file work on your machine? [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=laB7VaMz" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/laB7VaMz/)

Comment: i tried, nope, it doesn't. i am glad , you found solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, my solution was relating to multiple screens. I had the compositor on Screen A and Image Editor/Render Results on screen B.

When trying to pick the Matte ID (on screen A)

[image]

Using the *Image Editor*/*Render Results* (on Screen B), cryptomatte does not pick anything up.

However, if I setup the compositor on Screen B (i.e the same screen as the *Editor*/*Render Results*), cryptomatte does work.

Answer (score 0):

After going a little crazy hunting down the problem, I reset my Prefs to Factory Settings... which didn't fix the problem.

However, **resetting my Startup File** seemed to do the trick (File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings). It must have become corrupted somehow during my upgrade from 2.79 to 2.80, because opening older files seemed to use Cryptomatte just fine. I still don't know what caused the problem in the startup file, but... problem gone now.