# Why are my Cryptomatte Node's "Crypto.xx" inputs missing?

Tags: compositing-nodes, cryptomatte

I have several **Cryptomatte** output sockets on my **Render Layers** node, but no place to plug them in. The only input on my Cryptomatte node is "**Image**".

[image]

Render Layers node outputs:

- CryptoObject00
- CryptoObject01
- CryptoObject02

I am aware that there are three categories of Cryptomatte output: **Object**, **Material**, and **Asset**. Ticking more checkboxes increases the output socket count:

- CryptoObject00
- CryptoObject01
- CryptoObject02
- CryptoMaterial00
- CryptoMaterial01
- CryptoMaterial02
- CryptoAsset00
- CryptoAsset01
- CryptoAsset02

Just to be clear, the ***output*** sockets (of the Render Layers node) are showing up as expected. The ***input*** sockets (of the Cryptomatte node) are not.

Other users seem to get them to show up without any issues, so what is the difference?

Here is a screenshot taken from [another question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160308/), showing the inputs I expected to see:

[image]

Cryptomatte node input sockets:

- Crypto 00
- Crypto 01
- Crypto 02

These don't show up for me.

Using the `+` eyedropper I was able to grab an object name, for example: `Cube`. This name appeared in the **Matte ID** field, but did not not change the input sockets at all.

Comment: The input sockets are on a node which nowadays shows something in its name which is missing in your screenshot, "Cryptomatte **(Legacy)**". So that's an old version you are showing. The outputs are still there to work with the legacy cryptomatte node. For the new node you don't need them anymore. To pick objects, leave the cryptomatte layer at *.CryptoObject, to pick/add materials switch it to *.CryptoMaterial and for assets to *.CryptoAsset. By the way, the first answer below the question also shows the new node without the inputs.

Comment: By the way, I never used the old _Cryptomatte_ node and although I read something about how to use it, I have actually no idea why there are several outputs per layer type, because the information from which you can pick objects always seems to come completely from the output ending in "00".

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you for that info. Do you mean the *first* screenshot would be **legacy**, or the *second* screenshot would be? Sadly, the most recent version of Blender doesn't run on all of my machines, so to keep project files compatible between systems I am presently staying on 3.4. With this in mind, should I just route the `CryptoObject00` output into the `Image` input, use the eyedropper to pick the **Matte ID**, and move on with life? :-) With this configuration I can get the `Matte` output to produce a mask, and I see no issues.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann By the way, comparing manual pages for [3.4](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.4/compositing/types/matte/cryptomatte.html) and [3.6](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/compositing/types/matte/cryptomatte.html) there's no change in the node's appearance. Maybe that page of the manual is due for a screenshot update? **Edit:** Wait, here it is... the legacy node has [its own entry](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.4/compositing/types/matte/cryptomatte_legacy.html)!

Comment: 3.4 and 3.6? The old Cryptomatte node first appeared in 2.8 and was replaced by the new one in 2.93, so it's named "legacy" for quite a while now.